# Having trouble installing OpenSSL Cocoapod

Tags: xcode, openssl, cocoapods

I'm trying to install the OpenSSL Cocoapod in Xcode 9.4 and I get the following:

> [!] /bin/bash -c  set -e VERSION="1.0.2h" SDKVERSION=`xcrun --sdk
>   iphoneos --show-sdk-version 2> /dev/null`
>   MIN_SDK_VERSION_FLAG="-miphoneos-version-min=7.0"
>
> BASEPATH="${PWD}" CURRENTPATH="/tmp/openssl" ARCHS="i386 x86_64 armv7
>   armv7s arm64" DEVELOPER=`xcode-select -print-path`
>
> mkdir -p "${CURRENTPATH}" mkdir -p "${CURRENTPATH}/bin"
>
> cp "file.tgz" "${CURRENTPATH}/file.tgz" cd "${CURRENTPATH}" tar -xzf
>   file.tgz cd "openssl-${VERSION}"
>
> for ARCH in ${ARCHS} do   CONFIGURE_FOR="iphoneos-cross"
>
> if [ "${ARCH}" == "i386" ] || [ "${ARCH}" == "x86_64" ] ;   then
>       PLATFORM="iPhoneSimulator"
>       if [ "${ARCH}" == "x86_64" ] ;
>       then
>         CONFIGURE_FOR="darwin64-x86_64-cc"
>       fi   else
>       sed -ie "s!static volatile sig_atomic_t intr_signal;!static volatile intr_signal;!" "crypto/ui/ui_openssl.c"
>       PLATFORM="iPhoneOS"   fi
>
> export
>   CROSS_TOP="${DEVELOPER}/Platforms/${PLATFORM}.platform/Developer"
>   export CROSS_SDK="${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}.sdk"
>
> echo "Building openssl-${VERSION} for ${PLATFORM} ${SDKVERSION}
>   ${ARCH}"   echo "Please stand by..."
>
> export CC="${DEVELOPER}/usr/bin/gcc -arch ${ARCH}
>   ${MIN_SDK_VERSION_FLAG}"   mkdir -p
>   "${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk"
>   LOG="${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk/build-openssl-${VERSION}.log"
>
> LIPO_LIBSSL="${LIPO_LIBSSL}
>   ${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk/lib/libssl.a" 
>   LIPO_LIBCRYPTO="${LIPO_LIBCRYPTO}
>   ${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk/lib/libcrypto.a"
>
> ./Configure ${CONFIGURE_FOR}
>   --openssldir="${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk" > "${LOG}" 2>&1   sed -ie "s!^CFLAG=!CFLAG=-isysroot ${CROSS_TOP}/SDKs/${CROSS_SDK} !" "Makefile"
>
> make >> "${LOG}" 2>&1   make all install_sw >> "${LOG}" 2>&1   make
>   clean >> "${LOG}" 2>&1 done
>
> echo "Build library..." rm -rf "${BASEPATH}/lib/" mkdir -p
>   "${BASEPATH}/lib/" lipo -create ${LIPO_LIBSSL}    -output
>   "${BASEPATH}/lib/libssl.a" lipo -create ${LIPO_LIBCRYPTO} -output
>   "${BASEPATH}/lib/libcrypto.a"
>
> echo "Copying headers..." rm -rf "${BASEPATH}/opensslIncludes/" mkdir
>   -p "${BASEPATH}/opensslIncludes/" cp -RL "${CURRENTPATH}/openssl-${VERSION}/include/openssl"
>   "${BASEPATH}/opensslIncludes/"
>
> cd "${BASEPATH}" echo "Building done."
>
> echo "Cleaning up..." rm -rf "${CURRENTPATH}" echo "Done."
>
> cp: file.tgz: No such file or directory

This is the command I'm using in the podfile:

```
pod 'OpenSSL', '~> 1.0'
```

I've tried installing the Xcode Command Line Tools but this did not fix the problem.

Anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: If you can, try to switch to a different POD. That one is no longer maintained.

Workaround if you cannot switch:

```
curl https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-<your-version>.tar.gz > file.tgz
cp file.tgz /tmp/openssl #create directory if needed
sed 's/cp \\"file.tgz\\" \\"${CURRENTPATH}\/file.tgz\\"//' `find ~/.cocoapods|grep "OpenSSL/<your-version>/OpenSSL.podspec.json"`
pod install
```

"< your version >" would be e.g. "1.0.2j" for the URL and "1.0.210" for the grep

Comment: Where the `/tmp/openssl` should be located?

Comment: @kelin: I would like to help, but I am not sure whether I understand your question. Could you elaborate the problem you are running into?

Comment: @patric.shenke, it's just a question without specifying the particular problem.

Comment: @kelin: `/tmp/openssl` is already an absolute path specifier. So I would not know how to understand the question?

Comment: It's a local path on Mac actually. The directory will be created in the current folder, which is opened in terminal when you run the commands.

Comment: If the directory is created in the local folder, you are probably missing the first `/`. Please check your command lines.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll check later if I'll need this pod again.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing this issue also. Have not been able to resolve. Frustratingly this is happening on a Jenkins slave machine - whereas my own Mac has no issue with 'pod update' and seems to get OpenSSL without problem...

I since found out that the cocoapod-downloader had to be downgraded...for this to install... 
https://github.com/FredericJacobs/OpenSSL-Pod/issues/49

Comment: I ended up installing a different OpenSSL pod, the one in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884744/reduce-size-of-openssl-binary.

Answer (score 1):

I went around with several of the possible solutions, the one that worked for me was to downgrade cocoapods and the downloader. After OpenSSL is installed the pod install is done its fine to go back to the current ones. Exact steps:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
sudo gem install cocoapods-downloader -v 1.2.0
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.5.3
pod deintegrate
rm -rf /tmp/openssl
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

update:
just use

pod 'OpenSSL', :git => 'https://github.com/isee15/OpenSSL.git'

---

replace pod OpenSSL with OpenSSL-XM

or

replace "prepare_command" in find ~/.cocoapods|grep "OpenSSL/1.0.2j/OpenSSL.podspec.json"
with https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/3b17051d7e0bbb5c97420a7a6d3aa9b1f6b601db/Specs/3/2/e/OpenSSL-XM/1.0.210.1/OpenSSL-XM.podspec.json

Comment: OpenSSL-XM does not support `osx`.

Comment: Great drop-in replacement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I was trying to install a different cococapod, I got the same error.  For me the solution was to downgrade cococapods downloader.  This is the commands I used:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
sudo gem install cocoapods-downloader -v 1.2.0
```

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Patric's answer works for me. But to make the answer a little bit more clear here:

```
rm -rf /tmp/openssl; mkdir /tmp/openssl && cd /tmp/openssl;
curl https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2j.tar.gz > file.tgz
cd -;
sed -i 's/cp \\"file.tgz\\" \\"${CURRENTPATH}\/file.tgz\\"//' `find ~/.cocoapods|grep "OpenSSL/1.0.210/OpenSSL.podspec.json"`

pod install
```

**Note**:

- The `pod install` spent about 10 minutes on my mac air.
- Replace `1.0.2j` and `1.0.210` with your proper version if needed.
- If you want to try, downgrade the `cocoapods` and `cocoapods-downloader` is another solution, please refer [here](https://github.com/FredericJacobs/OpenSSL-Pod/issues/49#issuecomment-405018285).