# Reduce size of OpenSSL binary?

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl, receipt-validation, rmstore

I'm using [OpenSSL-for-iPhone](https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone) to generate a self compiled build of OpenSSL that I can use with the library [RMStoreAppReceiptVerifier](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/wiki/Receipt-verification) for receipt validation. Specifically, it builds OpenSSL 1.0.2k.

The problem I'm having is that libcrypto.a (45.3MB) and libssl.a (8.3MB) are very big and are adding a lot to my app's binary.

The classes I'm using in RMStoreAppReceiptVerifier only use:

```
#import <openssl/pkcs7.h>
#import <openssl/objects.h>
#import <openssl/sha.h>
#import <openssl/x509.h>
```

Is there anything I can do to reduce the size of OpenSSL? Or is another version better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using this https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL. OpenSSL-Universal pod. We use the same for storeReceipt verification. From what i checked the size of the framework is around 11 mb.

Comment: Thank you so much! Went from adding about 15 MB to a couple hundred of kilobytes!